# When Validation failed, How to keep the Bootstrap modal to stay as it is?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap modal which i will show when click a button.. That modal has form elements.. When it is all filled and submitted, it would hit the service and bring the response status. If the Response status is success, modal can be hide, otherwise it should stay as it is..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlRefId">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1">Issue Book</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class='form-group' id="Div6">
                        <label class='col-md-6 control-label' id='Label3'>Book Reference Number:</label>
                        <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <input id='refNo' type='text' name='refNo' class='form-control'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="__ID" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="mvSelectedBook()">Move to Selected Book</button> // mvSelectedBook() function given below
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>

    // On this function, the above modal will show
    $(document).on("click", ".modalClick", function (e) {
            if (document.getElementById("txtERPNo").value != "") {
                $('#mdlRefId').modal('show');
            }
            else {
                $('#mdlRefId').modal('hide');
                alertify.error("Please enter ERP number").dismissOthers();
            }
        });


      function mvSelectedBook() {
        // here ajax call performed and get response from the server side

        if (BookObj.Status != "SUCCESS") {

            if (document.getElementById("hdnBookRefIds").value == "")
                document.getElementById("hdnBookRefIds").value = BookObj.BookRefId;
            else
                document.getElementById("hdnBookRefIds").value += ',' + BookObj.BookRefId;

            populateSelectedBooks();
        }
        else {
            $('#mdlRefId').modal('show'); // This is not working now
        }
    }
```

When clicking the button, this script $('#mdlRefId').modal('show'); works and show the modal dialog.. But while getting response, it is not stay as it as when calling this script.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want is that the textbox, checkbox and others element keep their values when the submit wasn't successful?

Comment: Neither the `.modalClick` nor the `#txtERPNo` elements are included in your code, and it's not possible to replicate the problem without these.  Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry, I have found the solution for this.. Why it has not shown yet, because i have used  data-dismiss="modal" on the button where i called the function.. So in priority, it wins.. So the modal has hide automatically even it is failed

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?